# Cannot Resolve Constructor 'Beach(java.lang.string, java.lang.string)'

Tags: android-fragments

I implemented an upload image in a fragment. I have a model named Beach.java. However, I'm encountering an error

> Cannot resolve constructor 'Beach(java.lang.string,
>   java.lang.string)' on newBeach = new
>   Beach(beach_name.getText().toString(), uri.toString());

Here is the code in HomeFragment:

```
        imageFolder.putFile(saveUri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        mDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        imageFolder.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                newBeach = new Beach(beach_name.getText().toString(), uri.toString());
                            }
                        });
                    }
                })
```

Here is the code in Beach.class:

```
public class Beach {
private String name, image, description, price, menuID;

public Beach() {
}

public Beach(String name, String image, String description, String price, String menuID) {
    this.name = name;
    this.image = image;
    this.description = description;
    this.price = price;
    this.menuID = menuID;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String getMenuID() {
    return menuID;
}

public void setMenuID(String menuID) {
    this.menuID = menuID;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Beach class defines 2 constructors, one with no parameters :

```
 public Beach()
```

and one with 5 Strings :

```
public Beach(String name, String image, String description, String price, String menuID)
```

And you try to call a constructor with 2 Strings, which is no where to be found :

```
new Beach(beach_name.getText().toString(), uri.toString());
```

So you should add the below constructor to you Beach class :

```
public Beach(String name, String image) {
    this.name = name;
    this.image = image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have constructor with 2 parameters of String.
You can initialize class Beach with :

`new Beach(name, image, description, price, menuID)`

or with

`new Beach()`

If you want create with only 2 string add another constructor:

`public Beach(String name, String image){....}`